# Open Liberty 19.0.0.7 batchManagement-1.0 feature cannot be found

Tags: java, open-liberty

I am running my app on

> Open Liberty 19.0.0.7/wlp-1.0.30.cl190720190711-1115 on Eclipse OpenJ9 VM, version 11.0.3+7

And even though I added `<feature>batchManagement-1.0</feature>`, batch stuff does not work. According to OL docs - this feature should be available.

My features list:

```
 <featureManager>
   <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
   <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
   <feature>jpa-2.2</feature>
   <feature>jaxrsClient-2.1</feature>
   <feature>jsonb-1.0</feature>
   <feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>
   <feature>batchManagement-1.0</feature>
 </featureManager>
```

The error I am getting on OL start:

> [ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for batchmanagement-1.0

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch Management was added in 19.0.0.8. Please upgrade. Make sure you use the zip that contains everything, not the Java EE or Web Profile zips.